# How to write SOAP Authentication header with Ruby Savon

Tags: ruby, api, soap, savon

I am making calls to a SOAP based API for the first time, and I have the following info from the documentation:

> In your client, construct your authorization header as follows:
>
> 1 Concatenate the user name and password, for example:
>   ExampleUsername:ExamplePassword
>
> 2 Encode the string in base 64, for example:
>   RXhhbXBsZVVzZXJOYW1lOkV4YW1wbGVQYXNzd29yZA==
>
> 3 In your code, enter the Authorization header with the value Basic .
>
> Example Web Services header with encoded user name and password
>
> POST https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/AdminWebService HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>
> Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
>
> SOAPAction: ""
>
> Authorization: Basic RXhhbXBsZVVzZXJOYW1lOkV4YW1wbGVQYXNzd29yZA==

I am using the Savon gem to make my call. How would I, using Ruby 1.9.3 and the Savon gem, authenticate an API call `api_call` given the above information?

This is what I am using to setup the WSDL, or `client`.

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/v2/AdminWebService?wsdl&user=luigi@apitest.com")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include the authentification credentials in the SOAP header of your message.
Savon offers the :soap_header symbol for it.

Your example could look like this:

```
require 'savon'
require 'securerandom'

realm = Base64.strict_encode64("ExampleUsername:ExamplePassword")
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: "https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/v2/AdminWebService?wsdl",
    soap_header: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic #{realm}"},
    log: true,
    log_level: debug,
    pretty_print_xml: true
)
```

I couldn't test it this example because I lack the user credentials, but it passed "ruby -c".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This makes sense and generates the call as expected.

Comment: In savon v2 I had to use new syntax: `basic_auth: ["username", "password"],`

Comment: I think the initial problem was, that `basic_auth` didn't work for some reason. Therefore we had to fall back to the raw encoding of the http headers.

Comment: @house9 thanks, your solution worked. You saved my day!